# Import HTML file in Node.JS and pass variable into it

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I am creating an email system and I send an activation code to the users. To define the `msg` object to be sent to the user it has to follow this structure:

```js
    const msg = {
              to: req.body.email,
              from: "anakin@empire.net",
              subject: "Welcome to the Empire!",
              text: `Here is your access code! Shh, don't tell anyone - ${randomNum}`,
              html: CodeActivation <---
            };
```

For the `CodeActivation` HTML file I would like to pass `randomNum` into it which means I would need to actually import this file into Javascript to accept a variable then return the HTML (I've included the HTML file below).

This presents another obstacle, I have a length HTML file that I can't simply just wrap into a string.

Any suggestions would be awesome! Thank you for your time.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
<head>
 <!--[if gte mso 9]>
 <xml>
  <o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
  <o:AllowPNG/>
  <o:PixelsPerInch>96</o:PixelsPerInch>
  </o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
 </xml>
 <![endif]-->
 <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
 <meta name="format-detection" content="date=no" />
 <meta name="format-detection" content="address=no" />
 <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
 <meta name="x-apple-disable-message-reformatting" />
 <!--[if !mso]><!-->
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans:400,400i,700,700i&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
 <!--<![endif]-->
 <title>Email Template</title>
 <!--[if gte mso 9]>
 <style type="text/css" media="all">
  sup { font-size: 100% !important; }
 </style>
 <![endif]-->
 <!-- body, html, table, thead, tbody, tr, td, div, a, span { font-family: Arial, sans-serif !important; } -->
 

 <style type="text/css" media="screen">
  body { padding:0 !important; margin:0 auto !important; display:block !important; min-width:100% !important; width:100% !important; background:#f2f5f7; -webkit-text-size-adjust:none }
  a { color:#0047ab; text-decoration:none }
  p { padding:0 !important; margin:0 !important } 
  img { margin: 0 !important; -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; /* Allow smoother rendering of resized image in Internet Explorer */ }

  a[x-apple-data-detectors] { color: inherit !important; text-decoration: inherit !important; font-size: inherit !important; font-family: inherit !important; font-weight: inherit !important; line-height: inherit !important; }
  
  .btn-16 a { display: block; padding: 15px 35px; text-decoration: none; }
  .btn-20 a { display: block; padding: 15px 35px; text-decoration: none; }

  .l-white a { color: #ffffff; }
  .l-black a { color: #282828; }
  .l-pink a { color: #0047ab; }
  .l-grey a { color: #6e6e6e; }
  .l-purple a { color: #9128df; }

  .gradient { background: linear-gradient(to right, #388BFF 0%,#0047ab 100%); }

  .btn-secondary { border-radius: 10px; background: linear-gradient(to right, #9028df 0%,#0047ab 100%); }

  .cke_editable,
  .cke_editable a,
  .cke_editable span,
  .cke_editable a span { color: #282828 !important; }
  .tpl-content { padding: 0 !important; }
  .mcnPreviewText { display: none !important; }
    
  /* Mobile styles */
  @media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px), only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
   .mpx-10 { padding-left: 10px !important; padding-right: 10px !important; }

   .mpx-15 { padding-left: 15px !important; padding-right: 15px !important; }

   u + .body .gwfw { width:100% !important; width:100vw !important; }

   .td,
   .m-shell { width: 100% !important; min-width: 100% !important; }
   
   .mt-left { text-align: left !important; }
   .mt-center { text-align: center !important; }
   .mt-right { text-align: right !important; }
   
   .me-left { margin-right: auto !important; }
   .me-center { margin: 0 auto !important; }
   .me-right { margin-left: auto !important; }

   .mh-auto { height: auto !important; }
   .mw-auto { width: auto !important; }

   .fluid-img img { width: 100% !important; max-width: 100% !important; height: auto !important; }

   .column,
   .column-top,
   .column-dir-top { float: left !important; width: 100% !important; display: block !important; }

   .m-hide { display: none !important; width: 0 !important; height: 0 !important; font-size: 0 !important; line-height: 0 !important; min-height: 0 !important; }
   .m-block { display: block !important; }

   .mw-15 { width: 15px !important; }

   .mw-2p { width: 2% !important; }
   .mw-32p { width: 32% !important; }
   .mw-49p { width: 49% !important; }
   .mw-50p { width: 50% !important; }
   .mw-100p { width: 100% !important; }

   .mmt-0 { margin-top: 0 !important; }
  }

  
    /**
    * @tab Page
    * @section Body Background
    * @tip Set the styling for email background.
    * @style Body Background
    */
    .background-body {
     /*@editable*/ background-color: #f2f5f7;
    }

    /**
    * @tab Page
    * @section Footer Background
    * @tip Set the styling for Footer background.
    * @style Footer Background
    */
    .background-footer {
     /*@editable*/ background-color: #0047ab;
    }

    /**
    * @tab Page
    * @section Link Color
    * @tip Set the styling for link color.
    * @style Link Color
    */
    a {
     /*@editable*/ color: #0047ab;
    }

    /**
    * @tab Page
    * @section Button Background
    * @tip Set the styling for Buttons background.
    * @style Button Background
    */
    .btn-16 {
     /*@editable*/ background-color: #0047ab;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body class="body" style="padding:0 !important; margin:0 auto !important; display:block !important; min-width:100% !important; width:100% !important; background:#f2f5f7; -webkit-text-size-adjust:none;">
 <center>
  <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%;" bgcolor="#f2f5f7" class="gwfw">
   <tr>
    <td style="margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%;" align="center" valign="top">
     <table width="600" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="m-shell">
      <tr>
       <td class="td" style="width:600px; min-width:600px; font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; padding:0; margin:0; font-weight:normal;">
        <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
         <tr>
          <td class="mpx-10">
           <!-- Top -->
           <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
             <tr>
              <td class="text-12 c-grey l-grey a-right py-20" style="font-size:12px; line-height:16px; font-family:'PT Sans', Arial, sans-serif; min-width:auto !important; color:#6e6e6e; text-align:right; padding-top: 20px; padding-bottom: 20px;">
               <a href="#" target="_blank" class="link c-grey" style="text-decoration:none; color:#6e6e6e;"><span class="link c-grey" style="text-decoration:none; color:#6e6e6e;">View this email in your browser</span></a>
              </td>
             </tr>
            </table>           <!-- END Top -->
           
           <!-- Container -->
           <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
            <tr>
             <td class="gradient pt-10" style="border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0; padding-top: 10px;" bgcolor="#f3189e">
              <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
               <tr>
                <td style="border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;" bgcolor="#ffffff">
                 <!-- Logo -->
                 <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                  <tr>
                   <td class="img-center p-30 px-15" style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; text-align:center; padding: 30px; padding-left: 15px; padding-right: 15px;">
                    <a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="../HTML/img/stemuli_logo@2x.png" width="112" height="43" mc:edit="image_1" style="max-width:112px;" border="0" alt="" /></a>
                   </td>
                  </tr>
                 </table>
                 <!-- Logo -->
           
                 <!-- Main -->
                 <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                  <tr>
                   <td class="px-50 mpx-15" style="padding-left: 50px; padding-right: 50px;">
                    <!-- Section - Intro -->
                    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                     <tr>
                      <td class="pb-50" style="padding-bottom: 50px;">
                       <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                        <tr>
                         <td class="fluid-img img-center pb-50" style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; text-align:center; padding-bottom: 50px;">
                          <img src="https://www.psd2newsletters.com/templates/purple/images/img_intro_5.png" width="264" height="300" border="0" alt="" />
                         </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                         <td class="title-36 a-center pb-15" style="font-size:36px; line-height:40px; color:#282828; font-family:'PT Sans', Arial, sans-serif; min-width:auto !important; text-align:center; padding-bottom: 15px;">
                          <strong>Access Code</strong>
                         </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                         <td class="text-16 lh-26 a-center pb-25" style="font-size:16px; color:#6e6e6e; font-family:'PT Sans', Arial, sans-serif; min-width:auto !important; line-height: 26px; text-align:center; padding-bottom: 25px;">
                          Click on the button below to activate code, this is your requested account key code to log in with your email address (name@mail.com)
                         </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                         <td class="pb-30" style="padding-bottom: 30px;">
                          <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                           <tr>
                            <td class="title-22 a-center py-20 px-50 mpx-15" style="border-radius: 10px; border: 1px dashed #b4b4d4; font-size:22px; line-height:26px; color:#282828; font-family:'PT Sans', Arial, sans-serif; min-width:auto !important; text-align:center; padding-top: 20px; padding-bottom: 20px; padding-left: 50px; padding-right: 50px;" bgcolor="#f2f5f7">
                             <strong>CODE : <span class="c-purple" style="color:#9128df;">PURPLE123</span></strong>
                            </td>
                           </tr>
                          </table>
                         </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                         <td align="center">
                          <!-- Button -->
                          <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="min-width: 200px;">
                           <tr>
                            <td class="btn-16 c-white l-white" bgcolor="#f3189e" style="font-size:16px; line-height:20px; mso-padding-alt:15px 35px; font-family:'PT Sans', Arial, sans-serif; text-align:center; font-weight:bold; text-transform:uppercase; border-radius:25px; min-width:auto !important; color:#ffffff;">
                             <a href="#" target="_blank" class="link c-white" style="display: block; padding: 15px 35px; text-decoration:none; color:#ffffff;">
                              <span class="link c-white" style="text-decoration:none; color:#ffffff;">ACTIVATE CODE</span>
                             </a>
                            </td>
                           </tr>
                          </table>
                          <!-- END Button -->
                         </td>
                        </tr>
                       </table>
                      </td>
                     </tr>
                    </table>
                    <!-- END Section - Intro -->
                   </td>
                  </tr>
                 </table>
                 <!-- END Main -->
                </td>
               </tr>
              </table>
             </td>
            </tr>
           </table>
           <!-- END Container -->
           
          <!-- Footer -->
       <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
             <tr>
              <td class="background-footer p-50 mpx-15" bgcolor="#0047ab" style="border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px; padding: 50px;">
               <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                <tr>
                 <td align="center" class="pb-20" style="padding-bottom: 20px;">
                  <!-- Socials -->
                  <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                   <tr>
                    <td class="img" width="34" style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; text-align:left;">
                     <a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="https://www.psd2newsletters.com/templates/purple/images/ico_facebook.png" width="34" height="34" mc:edit="image_6" style="max-width:34px;" border="0" alt="" /></a>
                    </td>
                    <td class="img" width="15" style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; text-align:left;"></td>
                    <td class="img" width="34" style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; text-align:left;">
                     <a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="https://www.psd2newsletters.com/templates/purple/images/ico_instagram.png" width="34" height="34" mc:edit="image_7" style="max-width:34px;" border="0" alt="" /></a>
                    </td>
                    <td class="img" width="15" style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; text-align:left;"></td>
                    <td class="img" width="34" style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; text-align:left;">
                     <a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="https://www.psd2newsletters.com/templates/purple/images/ico_twitter.png" width="34" height="34" mc:edit="image_8" style="max-width:34px;" border="0" alt="" /></a>
                    </td>
                    
                   </tr>
                  </table>
                  <!-- END Socials -->
                 </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                 <td class="text-14 lh-24 a-center c-white l-white pb-20" style="font-size:14px; font-family:'PT Sans', Arial, sans-serif; min-width:auto !important; line-height: 24px; text-align:center; color:#ffffff; padding-bottom: 20px;">
                  <div mc:edit="text_12">
                  
                   <br />
                   <a href="tel:+17384796719" target="_blank" class="link c-white" style="text-decoration:none; color:#ffffff;"><span class="link c-white" style="text-decoration:none; color:#ffffff;">(738) 479-6719</span></a> - <a href="tel:+13697181973" target="_blank" class="link c-white" style="text-decoration:none; color:#ffffff;"><span class="link c-white" style="text-decoration:none; color:#ffffff;">(369) 718-1973</span></a>
                   <br />
                   <a href="mailto:info@website.com" target="_blank" class="link c-white" style="text-decoration:none; color:#ffffff;"><span class="link c-white" style="text-decoration:none; color:#ffffff;"></span></a> - <a href="www.website.com" target="_blank" class="link c-white" style="text-decoration:none; color:#ffffff;"><span class="link c-white" style="text-decoration:none; color:#ffffff;"></span></a>
                  </div>
                 </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                 <td align="center">
                  <!-- Download App -->
                  <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                   <tr>
                    <td class="img" width="117" style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; text-align:left;">
                     <a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="https://www.psd2newsletters.com/templates/purple/images/btn_appstore.png" width="117" height="40" mc:edit="image_10" style="max-width:117px;" border="0" alt="" /></a>
                    </td>
                    <td class="img" width="15" style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; text-align:left;"></td>
                    <td class="img" width="117" style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; text-align:left;">
                     <a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="https://www.psd2newsletters.com/templates/purple/images/btn_gplay.png" width="117" height="40" mc:edit="image_11" style="max-width:117px;" border="0" alt="" /></a>
                    </td>
                   </tr>
                  </table>
                  <!-- END Download App -->
                 </td>
                </tr>
               </table>
              </td>
             </tr>
            </table>    <!-- END Footer -->
               </table>           <!-- END Footer -->
                    <!-- END Footer -->
           
           <!-- Bottom -->
           <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
             <tr>
              <td class="text-12 lh-22 a-center c-grey- l-grey py-20" style="font-size:12px; color:#6e6e6e; font-family:'PT Sans', Arial, sans-serif; min-width:auto !important; line-height: 22px; text-align:center; padding-top: 20px; padding-bottom: 20px;">
               <a href="#" target="_blank" class="link c-grey" style="text-decoration:none; color:#6e6e6e;"><span class="link c-grey" style="white-space: nowrap; text-decoration:none; color:#6e6e6e;">UNSUBSCRIBE</span></a> &nbsp;|&nbsp; <a href="#" target="_blank" class="link c-grey" style="text-decoration:none; color:#6e6e6e;"><span class="link c-grey" style="white-space: nowrap; text-decoration:none; color:#6e6e6e;">WEB VERSION</span></a> &nbsp;|&nbsp; <a href="#" target="_blank" class="link c-grey" style="text-decoration:none; color:#6e6e6e;"><span class="link c-grey" style="white-space: nowrap; text-decoration:none; color:#6e6e6e;">SEND TO A FRIEND</span></a>
              </td>
             </tr>
            </table>           <!-- END Bottom -->
          </td>
         </tr>
        </table>
       </td>
      </tr>
     </table>
    </td>
   </tr>
  </table>
 </center>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Pick a [template language](https://colorlib.com/wp/top-templating-engines-for-javascript/) such as [nunjucks](https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/), then place an output instruction in the template:

```
<p>Your random number is {{randomNum}}</p>
```

… then run the template through the template library:

```
const html = nunjucks.render('template.html', { randomNum: get_a_random_number() });
```

Answer (score 0):

Save html somewhere on your server ex: otp.ejs with **SEND_CODE** text in your file.

```
fs.readFile(__dirname+"/otp.ejs", {encoding: 'utf-8'}, (err, data) => {
  if(err){
    if(err.code == 'ENOENT'){
      console.error(err.message);
    }else{
      console.error(err);
    }
  } else {
      data = data.replace(/SEND_CODE/g, randomNum);
      const msg = {
        to: req.body.email,
        from: "anakin@empire.net",
        subject: 'Code Verification',
        html   : data,
      };
  }
});
```

Don't forget to import **fs**